# Silverlight Display Mixed Content crashes IE

Tags: html, silverlight, internet-explorer, xap

So, I have an HTML page that includes a Silverlight xap file which plays a video.  It works correctly while running locally and on our DEV environment when using Chrome or FF.  The issue is when I am trying to view the video on our DEV environment using Internet Explorer.  When doing so, it prompts me to Display Mixed Content.  Whether I hit Yes or No, the browser crashes.  I am able to go into my options and Enable Display Mixed Content, which fixes the issue and the video shows up correctly on the DEV environment using IE.  But, this is not a good solution for a client facing site.  Is there a way around this message to prevent it from crashing the browser?

Comment: Is it an HTTPS page with your resource delivered via HTTP link? If so see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee264315(v=vs.85).aspx#web_devs)

Comment: Nah, it's not a https/http issue, but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround for this is to use JavaScript to open the HTML page that contains the video in a new window.  The user will still be prompted to Display Mixed Content, but it will not crash the browser and the video will play.